# Почему в owl-carousel на opencart вместо одного дополнительного изображения их 4?

Tags: opencart

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Добавляю в админке одно изображение, а вместо него их 4 на сайте.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как убрать лишние три? Посмотрел исходный код, у каждой из них класс owl-item cloned active прописан

Полазив сейчас по коду нашел место где выводится эта карусель, выводится она этим циклом

```
<div class="owl-carousel my-4 owl-images">
        <?php foreach ($images as $image) { ?>
            <div class="item">
                <a href="<?php echo $image['popup']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="thumbnail"><img src="<?php echo $image['thumb']; ?>" title="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" alt="<?php echo $heading_title; ?>" class="img-fluid" ></a>
            </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
```

проверяю массив $images через var_dump, выводится так

```
array(1) {
    [0]=>
    array(2) {
["popup"]=>
string(58) "http://shtory-cubic.local/image/cache/no_image-550x650.png"
["thumb"]=>
string(56) "http://shtory-cubic.local/image/cache/no_image-74x74.png"
```

}
}
то есть как-будто в нем два изображения... Каким образом их туда могло попасть два?

Comment: Скорее всего у вас в обэкте указано 2 значение loop: true и item: 4
нужно исправить

Comment: Посмотрел, стоит вот так - item:3 и loop: !1. item на 0 исправить, а loop на false?

Comment: item:1 попробуйте

Comment: попробовал, все равно их также 4 на сайте отображается